# How to defer after the fold video load after page loads in React/NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to up my lighthouse scores by loading a video after the page has fully loaded. It's after the fold and will not be seen until scroll so I want it to load everything on the page first so it can get a quick FCP and then load the video after everything.

This doesn't seem to work in terms of upping my Lighthouse score...

```
export default function AboutUs() {
  const [loadVideos, setLoadVideos] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadVideos(true)
  }, [])

   .....etc etc.....

    {loadVideos && (
          <video
            autoPlay
            muted
            playsInline
            loop
            preload="none"
            poster="/images/charge_poster.jpg"
          >
            <source src="/videos/charge.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        )}
   ..Closing tags etc
```

Is there a better way?
I don't want to load on scroll cause then the video will have to load when they are already there. Just load after HTML, CSS and Images preferably.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, `useEffect` subsumes the old `componentDidMount` along with a couple other lifecycle methods. The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) indicate that using `setState` in `componentDidMount` "will trigger an extra rendering, but [the rendering] will happen before the browser updates the screen." Without having tried something like it before, I'd kind of expect what you're expecting, but the above might explain why your test scores aren't improving.

Comment: _"I don't want to load on scroll"_ - I think that would be the best option. You can control how close the element needs to be from the fold to load it, it doesn't necessarily have to be visible to start loading.

Answer (score 0):

The preload attribute is ignored if autoplay is present.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).